# How can I learn to stop worrying and love ASP.NET MVC Forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

MVC encourages RESTful URL's, yet HTML forms by nature append the data in query string values. My action takes "text" as a string parameter. And my form is:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")) { %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("text") %>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
<% } %>
```

My action is:

```
public ActionResult Action(string text)
{
    ...
    return toInnocence;
}
```

There are two distinct URL's that your action can map to:

1. `~/Controller/Action/textvalue` thanks to your route map {controller}/{action}/{text}
2. `~/Controller/Action?text=textvalue` when submitted from a form

My question is:

How can I differentiate between two forms and do a redirect in the latter case? The second form breaks RESTful principle. What's the best practice there? I don't want to query RouteData.Values collection because it breaks the whole purpose of mapping request parameters to function arguments in a natural, straightforward way. This is a very basic scenario I expect MVC to handle this nicely.

The second form doesn't map to "text" parameter in the controller action. Why? How can I create overloaded versions of the same action then? Do I have to create a new action and use it for form submissions? Of course I can workaround all these but at the same time I'm afraid of missing the big picture somewhere.

It looks like people are getting along with these at ease so I feel like I'm the only one who is confused by route values against query strings.

**EDIT:** I looked at how Wikipedia does this. It uses separate actions for "form getter" and the actual restful URL and redirects from one to another as needed. I guess that would be the best way of doing it.

Comment: I don't see how the second form could be a violation of REST if the first form isn't.  Either they both are, or neither are.

Comment: If a query string perfectly describes what a URL is why do we have URL routing in the first place? We could get along with Controller.aspx?action=action&id=id form as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default operation of your browser is to put the values in the GET form in the query string. They will both resolve to a route of and go to the same action.

```
{ controller = "Controller", "Action", id = null, text = "textvalue" }
```

Because of the presence of the default route, this will correctly resolve.

The only way I can think of to do what you're asking is to change the form. Instead of submitting a "GET" request, submit as a PUT because you don't need a POST (you can do this with JS, with a friendly degrade to POST) and redirect to a GET.

Comment: So the best practice is to use separate actions for form submissions and URLs?

Comment: Check out #13 on Post-Redirect-Get: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx

IMO, a post is a bit much. You can use JS to create a put request. (Put requests will not create the typical browser "Resubmit POST data?" popup.)